# Multiple conversations

Tags: botframework

I am following the MS documentation for sequential conversations
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0
This is working fine, but I want to be able to run more than one of these.
For example to ask the following:
"I want to open a technical support case"
"I want to update my technical support case"
"I want to close my technical support case"

The example just revolves around just running one conversation so I don't know how to cater for multiple conversations.
Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks
Steve

Comment: You should better train your intent on LUIS to distinguish among the different conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking over using component dialogs, described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-complex-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). Component dialogs offer a means to branch conversations to handle specific portions of conversation and then return the user back to the main dialog.

In your case, you would query the user to what they are seeking as part of the main dialog. Then, once determined ("I want to close my technical case"), the dialog would branch to handle that specific conversation. After the case is closed, the component dialog would end and return the user back to the main dialog to determine if they want to perform any other actions.

This sample, [43.complex-dialog](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/43.complex-dialog), demonstrates how to setup a bot to utilize using component dialogs.

If you couple that with [LUIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/what-is-luis) to handle user intents, you should easily be able to manage a user's path while they navigate thru your bot. "I want to open a case" and "I want to close a case" would return either an "case open" or a "case close" intent which, when the intent is returned to the bot, would trigger the associated component dialog to open.

Hope of help!